# SQlite Update Record through Foreign Key

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-update, foreign-keys

for my code I need to update a record through a users ID number. When the values are entered into an entry box for `Exercise` and `Weight` a button is clicked to update the record. `Exercises` is the first table which has a foreign key `ID` which is linked to `MemberID` in the `memb` table. I have created an `UPDATE` query for this, this is the code:

```
    def Update(self):

    global MemberID

    connection = sqlite3.connect(r"E:\TESTING\Program\Accounts.db")

    cursor = connection.cursor()


    Exercise = self.Exercises.get()
    Weight = self.Weights.get()
    MemberID = self.ent_MemberID.get()

    List = [Exercise, Weight]


    cursor.execute("UPDATE Exercises SET Exercise=?, Weight=? WHERE ID = (SELECT MemberID FROM memb WHERE MemberID = ?);",(Exercise, Weight, MemberID))

    connection.commit()
```

It doesn't show any errors but is not entering the data into the table. This is the code I used to create the `Exercises` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Exercises` (
`Exercise`  TEXT,
`Weight`    INTEGER,
`Reps`  INTEGER,
`Sets`  INTEGER,
`ID`    INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY(`ID`),
FOREIGN KEY(`ID`) REFERENCES `memb`(`MemberID`)
);
```

Comment: You seem to be putting Python code directly in your SQL. That can't possibly work.

Comment: What's the point of the subquery? You're querying MemberID when you already have it. Why not just `"UPDATE Exercises SET Exercise=?, Weight=? WHERE ID = ?", (Exercise, Weight, MemberID)`? I think you might need to show your schema.

Comment: What is the purpose of the subquery? It always returns the same value that you give it as the parameter. And what is the value of `MemberID`? Show the row that you think should match.